# Python Zip & Move Script Error with Exit Code -1071120348 (0xC0280024), Exit Code Description - Lost

Tags: python, copy, shutil, python-zipfile, network-drive

I am using an automation tool known as ActiveBatch to call a python script which is zipping some files on a shared network drive and then moving that created zip to some other shared network drive.
The python script is turned into an exe file using pyinstaller which is actually getting called.

Most of the time the script works and returns exit code 0 but for sometimes it fails with
Exit Code - 1071120348 (0xC0280024)
Exit Code Description - Lost

In the script I am handling the error and sending back exit code 1 when some exception occurs.

---

```
# zipper.exe associated handle under CPU in resource monitor using pyinstaller and auto-py-to-exe

# required for logging to file
import logging
# https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#logging-to-a-file

# used for zipping files
from zipfile import ZipFile

# used for explorer related operations
import os

# used for getting current time
from datetime import datetime

# used for moving files
import shutil

# used for getting caller's name
import inspect

# used for exit handlers
import signal

# used to run commands
import subprocess

# to return error code
import sys

# importing network drive credentials
from credentials import Shared_resource, Username, Password

// src and dest are UNC Paths
def zipper(file_prefix, src, dest):

    # exception handling
    try:

        # set log file name with date and time
        zip_file_name = f'{file_prefix}_{datetime.now().strftime("%d-%m-%Y_%H-%M")}.zip'

        # set log level and logging to write output to console or log file
        log_format = "%(levelname)s | %(filename)s | %(lineno)s | %(asctime)s | %(message)s"
        logging.basicConfig(format=log_format,
                            datefmt="%d-%m-%Y %H:%M %z", level=logging.INFO, filename=f'logs_{zip_file_name[:-4]}.log')

        # get caller module's name and set as logger name
        frame = inspect.stack()[-1]
        caller_module = inspect.getmodulename(frame.filename)
        logger = logging.getLogger(caller_module)

        # log termination on keyboard interrupt
        def exit_gracefully(signum, frame):
            signame = signal.Signals(signum).name
            raise Exception(f'Termination... with signal {signame} ({signum})')

        signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, exit_gracefully)
        signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, exit_gracefully)

        # writing files to a zipfile
        with ZipFile(src+fr'\{file_prefix}_zips\{zip_file_name}', 'x') as zip_file:
            # dirpath : path to the directory
            # subdirs :  list of the names of the subdirectories in dirpath
            # files :  filenames is a list of the names of the non-directory files in dirpath.
            # crawling through directory and subdirectories
            for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(src):
                # remove particular directory from dirnames so walk won't traverse it
                if 'backup' in dirnames:
                    dirnames.remove('backup')
                if f'{file_prefix}_zips' in dirnames:
                    dirnames.remove(f'{file_prefix}_zips')

                for filename in filenames:
                    # join the two strings in order to form the full filepath.
                    absname = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(dirpath, filename))
                    arcname = absname[len(src) + 1:]

                    # skip temp excel files starting with '~$'
                    if not arcname.startswith('~$'):
                        # printing the list of all files to be zipped
                        logger.info(f'zipping {absname} as {arcname}')

                        # writing each file one by one
                        zip_file.write(absname, arcname)

        logger.info('All files zipped successfully!')

        # move zip file to different drive
        shutil.move(src+fr'\{file_prefix}_zips\{zip_file_name}', dest)

        # print gap between old and new log
        logger.info('Moved ZIP File'+'\n'*2)

    except Exception as exception:
        # no new scope created in try except
        # Program terminates after catching and logging exception
        logger.error("Error Occured")
        logger.exception(exception)
        # print gap between old and new log
        logger.info('\n'*2)
        sys.exit(1)
```

I am not able to find anything related to this exit code and cause for it in the log file and on the internet.

Edit 1 -

- Attaching the log file screenshot which doesn't log any error but program is lost.
  [image: stopped program logs]
- When the program works it logs as following
  [image: working program logs]

Comment: Can't you get a stack trace to see where the code stops working? Maybe run the script in debug mode? Or do you already know where the script breaks?

Comment: It logs "All files zipped successfully" and stops

Comment: Then it's either a problem with the line `shutil.move(src+fr'\{file_prefix}_zips\{zip_file_name}', dest)` or the script completes successfully and the error post-script

Comment: Yes problem is in moving a large zip file slowly to another shared drive. The error is not getting logged in the log file even after catching all exceptions. The program is silently getting killed as it doesn't log the final step that is "Moved ZIP File".